How to add text based on value of two columns
I'm trying to write a formula that would show "Yes" when one column is between 10 and 249, and another column has specific test like "Blue" or "Red" or "Green".
I can get the first part it (10 < X < 249) using IF/AND but I'm stuck when it comes to adding the logic for the second column. That the second column could contain one of several words is getting me stuck.
Here is how far I've gotten:
=IF(AND(M2>=10, M2 <249), "Yes", 0) 
but then what? I tried adding another logic piece after M2<249 for (OR(S2("Blue", "Red", "Green"))), "Yes", 0)
No luck, but I feel like I might be close?

Try: =IF(AND(M2>=10,M2<249), IF(OR(S2="Blue",S2="Red",S2="Green"),"YES",0),0)
You can nest as many IFs as you like,
Alternativly: =IF(AND(AND(M2>=10,M2<249),OR(S2="Blue",S2="Red",S2="Green")),"YES,0)
I think the second one might even be a bit faster, again you can nest ANDs and ORs as you like.

Alternatively: =IF(AND(M2>=10,M2<149,OR(S2="Blue",S2="Red",S2="Green")),"Yes",0)

@Luuk even better indeed!

I would recommend to "externalize" the values to check against.
Furthermore - for the sake of "readability" - I would use a LET-formula, that "explains" how the check is working.
=LET(isWithinMargin,AND(A2>=configMargins[Min],A2<=configMargins[Max]),
     hasAllowedColor,ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,configAllowedColors[allowed colors],0)),
IF(isWithinMargin*hasAllowedColor,"OK","not OK"))


